# Conflict between memory management descriptions in ObjC book and official docs

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

I'm trying to learn/understand what happens and why when working with or creating various objects. (Hopefully to LEARN from the docs.)

I'm reading "Programming in Objective-C 2.0" (2nd edition, by Steven Kochan). On page 408, in the first paragraph is a discussion of retain counts:

> Note that its reference count then goes to 2. The `addObject:` method does this automatically; if you check your documentation for the `addObject:` method, you will see this fact described there.

So I read the `addObject:` docs:

> Inserts a given object at the end of the array.

There, **the description is missing**, while other items, like `arrayByAddingObject:`, **state it**:

> Returns a new array that is a copy of the receiving array with a given object added to the end.

Where in the reference does it indicate that `addObject:` increases the retain count? Given the presence of ARC, I should still understand what these methods are doing to avoid bugs and issues. What does ARC bring to this? (Going to read that again...)

Comment: I'm more interested in understanding where these concepts are written than solving the question about an array method. I want to be able to 'reference the documents' to piece together answers to questions like this... Einstein gave a good answer. **Where can I find the answer** for working with more complicated objects?

Comment: Any book that discusses retain counts in absolute terms should be considered suspect.

Comment: @bbum This book, like many, is trying to explain the subtleties of memory management, with an example showing what happens after various methods occur. It is difficult to reach **every** reader.

Comment: Yeah -- it is an awful example;  it is, effectively, teaching the student that there is some kind of absolute, predictable, meaning to the actual value of the retain count.  While that works in dead simple cases, it totally breaks down as soon as you do anything real -- student is left baffled without tools to deal with reality.  The retain count should be treated as a delta;  it gets increased and decreased, you keep it in balance and all is good.

Comment: @David: If you think my title edit misconstrues your meaning, please re-edit it however you like. I was just trying to make it more well-defined -- originally it was on the vague/broad side. Something like "How do I determine the memory management implications of Cocoa methods?" would be a bit better than your original title.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau Your edit improved the question, and helped bring in more answers. It's a win.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you should look in the "most global" spot for information about anything in the Cocoa APIs.   Since memory management is pervasive across the system APIs *and* the APIs are consistent in their implementation of the Cocoa memory management policy, you simply need to read and understand the Cocoa memory management guide.

Once understood, you can safely assume that all system APIs implement to that memory management policy unless *explicitly documented otherwise*.

Thus, for NSMutableArray's `addObject:` method, it would **have to** `retain` the object added to the array or else it would be in violation of that standard policy.

You'll see this throughout the documentation.  This prevents every method's documentation from being a page or more long *and* it makes it obvious when the rare method or class implements something that is, for whatever reason (sometimes not so good), an exception to the rule.

---

In the "Basic Memory Management Rules" section of the memory management guide:

**You can take ownership of an object using retain.**

> A received object is normally guaranteed to remain valid within the
>   method it was received in, and that method may also safely return the
>   object to its invoker. You use retain in two situations: (1) In the
>   implementation of an accessor method or an init method, to take
>   ownership of an object you want to store as a property value; and (2)
>   To prevent an object from being invalidated as a side-effect of some
>   other operation (as explained in “Avoid Causing Deallocation of
>   Objects You’re Using”).

(2) is the key;  an NS{Mutable}Array must `retain` any added object(s) exactly because it needs to prevent the added object(s) from being invalidated due to some side-effect.   To not do so would be divergent from the above rule and, thus, would be explicitly documented.

Comment: Succinctly put. The **Cocoa memory management guide** looks like the **object** to read (integrate) & digest.

Comment: Try as I might, to find what you suggest, the backing for one sentence evades me: 'Thus, for NSMutableArray's addObject: method, it would have to retain the object added to the array or else it would be in violation of that standard policy.' Using the [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-SW2 ] (Memory Management Programming Guide - Ownership Policy), I cannot find the link between (eg) `addObject:` and 'have to retain'. Suggestions??

Comment: @DavidC bbum has great advice, however you should be looking at the **Advanced Memory Management Guide** because it covers cocoa objects, and not the link that you provided which is for core foundation objects.  See:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i See both the **Memory Management Policy** (bullet 2), and the **Practical Memory Management** which covers collections in more detail.

Comment: @inafziger & bbum This **Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide** in the iOS library is really the place to find the answer to this question. As a side note, they don't highlight or bring focus to the idea of Object Ownership, found on **Memory Management Policy** And, the array example is really loud in **Practical Memory Management**

Answer (score 7):

Great question, I'm glad to see someone actually reading the docs *and trying to understand them*!

Since you are looking for how to research answers using Apple's documentation more so than the actual answer itself, here is how I found the answer:

- First I look at the class reference for `addObject:` which is a method of `NSMutableArray` and there is no mention of memory management.
- Then I look at the **Overview** section at the top...  Hmmm, still no luck.
- Since the behavior might be inherited from a parent class, I look at the **Inherits from** section at the top of the class reference and see that `NSArray` is the most immediate parent.  Let's check there:
- Under the **Overview** There is one small section about retain's:

> **Special Considerations**
>
> In most cases your custom NSArray class should conform to Cocoa’s
>   object-ownership conventions. Thus you must send retain to each object
>   that you add to your collection and release to each object that you
>   remove from the collection. Of course, if the reason for subclassing
>   NSArray is to implement object-retention behavior different from the
>   norm (for example, a non-retaining array), then you can ignore this
>   requirement.

- Okay, I'm still not happy...  Where next?  The parent class of `NSArray` is `NSObject` and I know that it won't be covered there in this case (from experience) so I won't bother checking that.  (If the parent was another class or something that might be covered by NSObject, I would keep moving up the tree until I found something.)
- The **Companion Guides** usually contains a lot of good information for these types of classes.  Let's try the first one, *Collections Programming Topics*.
- The first section (after **Overview**) is **Accessing Indexes and Easily Enumerating Elements: Arrays**.  Sounds promising!  Click on **Relevant Chapters: “Arrays: Ordered Collections”**
- There it is under **Array Fundamentals** along with a link to even more information:

> And when you add an object to an NSMutableArray object, the object
>   isn’t copied, (unless you pass YES as the argument to
>   initWithArray:copyItems:). Rather, an object is added directly to an
>   array. In a managed memory environment, an object receives a retain
>   message when it’s added; in a garbage collected environment, it is
>   strongly referenced. When an array is deallocated in a managed memory
>   environment, each element is sent a release message. For more
>   information on copying and memory management, see “Copying
>   Collections.”

Comment: @inafziger Very good answer. The core is in the 1st bullet list. (We must think alike.)

Comment: @DavidC: Glad I could help another Florida pilot!  (Or really, anyone, but this is a bonus.  :) )

Comment: Well, I guess the conclusion is that the docs are not the 1st source of definitive info. Imagine, doing this for the methods we write in code ??

Comment: Well, it **is** (buried) in the docs...  They just don't make it easy!

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the specific quotes from the docs! I think this is the only question on SO where there is a better answer than bbum's (above).

Answer (score 6):

The book must be referring to out of date documentation because you are correct it doesn't mention anything about the retain count. It does in fact retain the object though. The way you need to think of it is not in terms of retain counts (which are useless) but rather ownership.  Especially so when using ARC.

When you add an object to an `NSMutableArray`, it is taking ownership of that object (in ARC terminology it has a strong reference to it).

"What does ARC bring to this?"

ARC does nothing different. All ARC does (besides some optimization) is add the same release, retain, and autorelease statements that you would add yourself without using ARC. All you need to care about is that once you add an object to the array, it will live at least as long as the array.

---

And the `arrayByAddingObject:` method creates a new `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`) containing the object you're passing, and keeps a strong reference to the passed object. The actual array object that it creates has no references yet unless you assign it to either an ivar, property, or local variable. What you assign it to determines it's lifespan.

---

Basically even without ARC, it's best to think of object life-cycles in terms of ownership, ARC just formalizes that. So because of that, when using the frameworks, it doesn't matter when retains happen or don't happen, you are only responsible for your objects until you pass ownership to another object and you can trust that the framework will keep the object alive as long as it needs it.

Now of course you have to intuit what constitutes ownership. For instance delegate properties are often `assign`, or in ARC `unsafe_unretained` or `weak`, to prevent circular retains cycles (where two objects each retain each other), though are sometimes retained/strong so you need to look into those on a case by case basis.

And also in cases like key value observing and NSNotification observing the object you are observing does not retain the observer.

But those are really exceptions to the rule. Generally you can assume a strong reference.

Regarding this sentence above: "The actual array object that it creates has no references yet unless you assign it to either an ivar, property, or local variable. What you assign it to determines it's lifespan." I'll try to explain:

When you run this piece of code: `[someArray arrayByAddingObject:someObject];` you've instantiated a new `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` object (depending on which object type `someArray` is) but you haven't actually assigned it to any reference. That means that if you're using ARC, it may be immediately released afterwards, or if not using ARC, it will be released when it's autoreleasepool is drained (probably on the next iteration of that thread's runloop).

Now if instead you did this: `NSArray *someOtherArray = [someArray arrayByAddingObject:someObject];` you now have a reference to the newly created array, called someOtherArray. In this case, this is a local variable who's scope is only within whichever set of `{` `}` it resides (so it could be inside an `if` statement, a loop, or a method. Now if you do nothing else with it, it will die sometime after it's scope ends (it isn't guaranteed to die right away, but that isn't important, you just can't assume it lives longer).

Now if in your class you have an iVar (instance variable) declared in the header like `NSArray *someOtherArray;` (which is strong by default in ARC) and you run `someOtherArray = [someArray arrayByAddingObject:someObject];` somewhere in your class, the object will live until you either remove the reference (`someOtherArray = nil`), you overwrite the reference (`someOtherArray = someThirdArray`), or the class is deallocated. If you were not using ARC, you would have to make sure to retain that to achieve the same effect (`someOtherArray = [[someArray arrayByAddingObject:someObject] retain];` which is essentially what ARC is doing behind the scenes).

Or you may have a property declared instead like `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *someOtherArray` in which `self.someOtherArray = [someArray arrayByAddingObject:someObject];` would achieve the same effect but would use the proprety accessor (`setSomeOtherArray:`) or you could still use `someOtherArray = [someArray arrayByAddingObject:someObject];` to set the iVar directly (assuming you `@synthesized` it).

Or assuming non-ARC, you might have declared the property like `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *someOtherArray` in which `self.someOtherArray = [someArray arrayByAddingObject:someObject];` would behave exactly as ARC would, but when setting the iVar directly you would still need to add that retain manually.

I hope that clears things up a bit, please let me know if there's anything I glossed over or left out.

---

As you mentioned in your comment, the key here is intuitively knowing when an object would be considered owned by another one or not. Luckily, the Cocoa frameworks follow a pretty strict set of conventions that allow you to make safe assumptions:

- When setting an `NSString` property of a framework object (say the `text` property of a `UILabel` for example) it is always copied (if anyone knows of a counter-example, please comment or edit). So you don't have to worry about your string once you pass it. Strings are copied to prevent a mutable string from being changed after it's passed.
- When setting any other property other than `delegate`, it's (almost?) always retained (or strong reference in ARC)
- When setting delegate properties, it's (almost?) always an assign (or weak reference) to prevent circular retain cycles. (For instance, object `a` has a property `b` that is strong referenced and `b` has a strong referenced delegate property. You set `a` as the delegate for `b`. Now `a` and `b` are both strongly referencing each other, and neither object will ever reach a retain count of 0 and will never reach it's dealloc method to dealloc the other object. `NSURLConnection` is a counter-example that does strongly reference it's delegate, because it's delegate is set via a method -- see that convention below -- and it's convention to nil out or release an `NSURLConnection` after it completes rather than in `dealloc`, which will remove the circular retain)
- When adding to an array or dictionary, it's always retained (or strong reference).
- When calling a method and passing block(s), they are always copied to move them from the stack (where they are initially created for performance purposes) into the heap.
- Methods that take in object parameters and don't return a result immediately are (always? I can't think of any that don't) either copying or retaining (strong referencing) the parameters that you pass to ensure that the method can do what it needs to with them. For instance, `NSURLConnection` even retains it's delegate because it's passed in via a method, whereas when setting the delegate *property* of other objects will not retain, as that is the convention.

It's suggested that you follow these same conventions in your own classes as well for consistency.

Also, don't forget that the headers of all classes are available to you, so you can easily see whether a property is retain or assign (or strong or weak). You can't check what methods do with their parameters, but there's no need because of the convention that parameters are owned by the receiver.

Comment: Uggh. Great answer (for me), until below the line. Thanks for directing the question (and reading) into 'strong & weak' references.

Comment: Can you explain what you find wrong with the part below the line?

Comment: Also to clarify that last part, the newly created array keeps a strong reference to all of the objects in it, so it has a strong reference to all of the objects in the first array as well as the additional object that was passed to `arrayByAddingObject:`.

Comment: I didn't say 'wrong'. Please remember, I'm wanting to learn what the docs provide. It is new and confusing because of: 'and keeps a strong reference to the passed object. The actual array object that it creates has no references yet...' Still trying to get my head around that.

Comment: Just added a bunch to my answer, hopefully that clarifies things a bit

Comment: Very thorough explanation. It comes down to one sentence: Now of course you have to intuit what constitutes ownership. But, I don't get how to see that (in future looks into docs). In the case of this array discussion, are we following the 2nd rule of [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-SW2) ?

Comment: Added another section at the end to address your last comment